# Was this question incorrectly closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question linked here [Is NATO justified in treating the war in Ukraine as insurgency?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/71840/38304). The stated reason for closure is

> The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician. It does not appear to be a good-faith effort to learn more about governments, policies and political processes as defined in the help center.

The question is indeed somewhat critical about NATO, but this hardly constitute "`to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician.`"

As with [previous unexplained closure](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6193/38304), I am looking for opinions before passing it further to the SE moderators.

Comment: See https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4723/what-is-a-push-question

Answer (score 11):

The problem with that question is that it's **not** a question. It's an argument, with a question tacked on to the end.

If we look at the question, we see a number of arguments and assertions, all of which are highly questionable and none of which are supported by any evidence:

1. An assertion that NATO is pursuing an insurgency in Ukraine
2. An assertion that the aid to Ukraine isn't sufficient for a real war
3. A claim that this means NATO doesn't care about Ukraine or Eastern NATO members
4. A claim that insurgencies can never defeat a real military force
5. A claim that insurgency is impossible in Ukraine due to their terrain and the Ukrainian people

Then you stick a question on the end which amounts to: "If we accept my claims, NATO is doing something stupid. Why is NATO stupid?" On this site, a Question needs to be a *real question*, not an argument. If the main aim of your question is to push an argument, or if the question requires you to accept a list of questionable assertions, then it's a attempt to promote an argument or position, not to "learn more about governments, policies and political processes".

A way to make this question on-topic would be to focus just on things which are objective. You might ask, "Why is NATO only giving Ukraine man-portable weapons, rather than heavy equipment that would be more helpful in a direct war?" This question would get at what you want to learn about, without spending so much time pushing a specific argument.

Comment: I didn't call NATO *"stupid"* - I was asking why tehy do what they do, and not more (or elss). I still don't see how *to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician.* applies here.

Comment: @RogerVadim while giving context is good, your context makes NATO look stupid (or at the very least incompetent). Context that makes somebody/something look stupid is often viewed as pushing a specific cause, especially when they do so much of it. A way to get your question reopened IMO would be to simply find a source saying that NATO supports an insurgency instead of an actual war (a biased source can be used, although not ideal, if it has a disclaimer saying that it is biased), and then asking why NATO supports an insurgency instead of an actual war.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica I don't see how I make them look stupid - it is *your subjective interpretation* of what what I wrote, which has more to do with *your own biases* than anything I wrote. I merely outlined how I interpret their actions and why I don't understand them.

Comment: @RogerVadim That's exactly the problem. Your post was an argument about what you think NATO is doing and why it doesn't make sense. That's fine on a discussion forum, but this isn't one of those. It's a question and answer site, and your posts should be focused on a open question, not an argument or narrative.

Comment: As a general rule, the less "context" and "introduction" your question has, the better, and if your question requires you to lay out arguments or givens which must be accepted for the question to make any sense, it's a "push question", and not appropriate here.

Comment: @divibisan an advanced question inevitably invovles an argument. Otherwise it likely can be answered by doing a bit of research.

Comment: @RogerVadim That's the kind of questions this site is for. It's **not a debate forum** where people post arguments and others debate them. You could have asked your question much more simply: "NATO is providing Ukrainian forces with plenty of man-portable weapons which would be useful in an insurgency, but not heavy equipment for a direct clash with the Russian army. Why are they limiting their aid in this way?". This formulation gets at your question, but leaves it open for different kinds of answers or approaches, and doesn't presume certain facts which many will disagree with.

Comment: @divibisan for those who disagree with the facts, there is a comment section. Anyhow, your critics of my question do not seem to get closer to the actual closure reason: `to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician`.

Comment: @RogerVadim Again, that close reason covers all types on ["push questions"](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4723/19301) that exist mostly or entirely to argue a point. You should read the meta page the Fizz linked above to understand more. If you dislike the way this site works, there are countless other places on the internet to discuss or argue or publish your arguments. If you're going to post here, you need to accept that your posts will be subject to the rules and community driven moderation this site is based on.

Comment: @divibisan I have some experience with the site and a pretty good idea of how it works. I am just trying to raise a bit the level of discussions in this community.

Comment: Then, you have missed the point. **Stack Exchange does not *do* "discussion", it does Question-and-Answers.**

Comment: @RogerVadim I think it's a perfectly reasonable aspiration *in principle* to "raise a bit the level of discussions". While Nij points out that Each Stack Exchange site is a Q&A site, we work within that format to discuss things all the time. But we must always adhere to the Q&A format otherwise this stops being Stack Exchange, and as currently written your post is a "push question" as it primarily articulates a position. If it quoted a position of a notable figure and asked if their arguments are valid or flawed that might help somewhat, but SE can't survive if question posts become positions.

Comment: @uhoh it was a Q&A question with background explained. Most questions here are of the kind "Did X say/did Y", which are Q&A, but poorly researched - and normally subject to closure under SE rules... I think anyone who read the question know what the "problem" is, but I see no point to fight about it

Comment: @Nij perhaps I missed your earlier comments relevant to the OP... I don't quite understand what your pronouncement refers to, and why you think that your level of understanding is superior to mine.

Comment: @RogerVadim I don't see any evidence of "research". Unless you can explain otherwise by referring to sources, to readers it's just your position. I always begin my Politics SE question by quoting a source or three, then if I have to add any of my own perspectives for the purposes of explaining the question further, *I'll add it separately and use the first person voice.* In Stack Exchange especially, it's not what you think you said that counts, it's how readers perceive it when reading or sometimes simply skimming.

Comment: @uhoh this is too generic to make any sense. Let's not continue debating just for the sake of debating - it doesn't work in online forums, since many people read and reread what you wrote, and quickly spot logical fallacies,etc

Comment: @RogerVadim I have asked over 5,000 Stack Exchange questions including about 500 hot network questions, thereforfe I have some sense for what will fly and what will be shot down in Stack Exchange. There is no logic to it *per se* but if you want to avoid your questions being closed you might abandon logic for some more effective rules of thumb. Bottom line, don't ask "push-questions" whether you acknowledge there is such a thing or not.

Comment: @uhoh 1) as long as you use biased language to describe my question, your arguments won't fly, because I don't agree with these characterizations; 2) your default assumption is that the decision to close was correct, and you simply try to justify it - this is a logical fallacy; 3) plenty of questions here make critical comments about Russian army or call Putin "autocrat/dictator" without being dismissed as "push questions", so arguing of it as simple application of forum rules is not convincing.

Comment: I agree  it does appear you don't understand several things here. I'm not sure I want to bother spending the time to help you develop it, though. If you want to post your opinions and be challenged, go start a blog. Come back to Stack Exchange when you want to honestly to ask questions and get the answers to them.

Comment: @RogerVadim if you add links to those several other questions back into your meta question here and show how they are similar in character it could add to your argument that the close was out of the norm. We can't really say "correct" or "incorrect" as it's voting-driven. reopening a question is also voting-driven, so the more compelling your arguments that similar questions are well received, the better the chances of it getting reopened. This is how Stack Exchange works, so either we embrace it or we don't.

Comment: @uhoh the question was not closed by voting, but by a decision of a single moderator.

Comment: @RogerVadim That’s not true. If you look at this question, it clearly says it was closed by 5 votes from users

Comment: @divibisan this is not what I see.

Comment: *The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician. It does not appear to be a good-faith effort to learn more about governments, policies and political processes as defined in the help center. (Private feedback)* no names.

Comment: @RogerVadim [This question?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/71840/19301) I see it - not sure why you wouldn’t, since you should be able to. Even if it was a mod, they’re just users who volunteer and get elected. While their votes count for more, they can still be overruled just like any other user

Comment: @RogerVadim the notice at the top says "Closed 10 days ago by A, B, C, D, E (Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege)" where the names of the five close voters is visible to the post author (you I assume) and anyone above a certain reputation threshold. It looks like it was a normal close vote by five community members.

Comment: @RogerVadim Your post is certainly a reasonable exercise for a group of people, it's just that the format you've used is incompatible with how Politics SE is currently set up. SE is open to pretty much the entire planet's internet; there have to be constraints to keep it from turning into just another internet mess like Facebook. One of them is that we don't use questions to argue positions; "X is Y, prove me wrong". It can be refactored to "Does X = Y?" or "Why doesn't Z think X = Y?" but you need to move your arguments to an answer post...

Comment: @RogerVadim and generally you wait for a few other answers first before adding your answer to the mix to make it clear you are not using the post to push a specific viewpoint. If you would still like to push or vet an argument of your own, then maybe Facebook is what you are looking for and Stack Exchange will not serve your needs in this particular case.